# Protractor Page objects - TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'methodName'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, pageobjects

I'm trying to write a simple test using page objects pattern - based on the '[docs/page-objects](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/page-objects.md)'.

I created a file describing the page object and other using this page object to test a page.

```
//page object
var LoginPage = function() {

this.userInput = browser.driver.findElement(by.id('username'));
this.pwdInput  = browser.driver.findElement(by.id('password'));
this.btnEnter  = browser.driver.findElement(by.id('btnLogin'));

this.get = function(){
    browser.get('http://example.com');
};

this.setUser = function (user){
    this.userInput.sendKeys(user);  
};

this.setPasswd = function (password) {
    this.pwdInput.sendKeys(password);
};

this.clickBtnEnter = function (){
    btnEnter.click();
};};
```

The spec file:

```
var loginPage = require('./LoginPage.js');
describe('myApp', function() {
  it('should save contract config', function (){        
    loginPage.get();
    loginPage.setUser('userid');
    loginPage.setPasswd('passwd');
    loginPage.clickBtnEnter();
  });
});
```

The following error is shown when I run this test: **TypeError: Object # has no method 'get'** - at this line: loginPage.get();.

When I was searching for this problem I found various approaches about using page objects in Protractor, such as [Astrolable](https://github.com/stuplum/astrolabe).
Now I am not sure about the correct usage of page objects.

Do you have any ideas about how I can fix this test?

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying the above syntax (no success) I rewrote the page object using the [Astrolable](https://github.com/stuplum/astrolabe). Now it works! My test looks like this:

```
//pageobject
'use strict';
var env = require('./environment.js')

var LoginPage = function () {
  browser.driver.get('http://example.com');
};

LoginPage.prototype = Object.create({}, {

userInput:         {    get: function()    { return browser.driver.findElement(by.id('username'));}},
pwdInput:          {    get: function() { return browser.driver.findElement(by.id('password'));}},
btnEnter:          {    get: function()    { return browser.driver.findElement(by.id('btnLogin'));}},

setUser:           {     value: function (loginName) {
    this.userInput.sendKeys(loginName);        
}},

setPasswd: { value: function (loginPass) {
    this.pwdInput.sendKeys(loginPass);
}},

clickBtnEnter:    {    get: function()    { return this.btnEnter.click();}}    
});

module.exports = LoginPage;
```

Spec file:

```
'use strict';
var loginPage = require('./LoginPage.js');

describe('myApp', function() {
    var poLogin = new loginPage();

    it('should save contract config', function (){        
        poLogin.setUser('userid');
        poLogin.setPasswd('passwd');
        poLogin.clickBtnEnter;
    });
});
```

Now it is working fine.
Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Ensure you have the following in your `LoginPage.js` file

```
module.exports = LoginPage;
```

Add the missing `new` keyword

```
var LoginPage = require('./LoginPage.js');
var loginPage = new LoginPage();
```

Comment: I edited the files as suggested but now I have a different error: _C:\Users\flavio.meira\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:109
  var template = new Error(this.message);
                 ^
NoSuchElementError: no such element
  (Session info: chrome=36.0.1985.143)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267521,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)_. **PS:** It's not the full error output

Comment: It is what is says, the element is not found at the testing page. You're asking a different question now, you should open a new question and close this one as answered since your missing method name error got fixed. Don't forget to always mention you're using Windows, there are particular problems there sometimes ;)

Comment: Hi elgalu. The element is not found because the page is not loaded. The 'get' method didn't work. Because of it no element is found. It seems like missing the browser driver. Tks for answering. PS: the Chrome browser shows this url: `data:,`

Comment: The Leo proposal works for me, without need to include Astrolable.