# Object #<Object> has no method 'getInstance' when trying to run Protractor tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, end-to-end

When I am attempting to run my Protractor tests from the command line all of my tests fail because whenever I try to access the `protractor` object it does not have the methods I need. The exact error is:

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'getInstance'

So this seems to have been a [reported](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/36) and [fixed](https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/90f0a942b09faff5924674a20ce7705b6d685eba) issue, yet I cannot seem to resolve my particular situation. It also seems to be semi-related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25518874/protractor-page-objects-typeerror-object-object-has-no-method-methodname) question, but because it arose for me after updating my node_modules I feel like my underlying issue is different. Up until updating my Protractor everything worked just fine.

I installed it globally and used `npm link protractor` to link my local instance to my global instance (located at `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor`), but I still for the life of me cannot figure out what is wrong.

The exact code where I'm calling `protractor` is a page object file that looks like:

```
module.exports = function() {

    var ptor = protractor.getInstance();

    this.get = function() {
        browser.get('http://localhost');
        this.title = ptor.getTitle();
    };

};
```

The code instantiating the page object is as follows:

```
var Login = require('./pageObjects/Login.po.js');
...
var LoginPage = new Login();
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't need to call `protractor.getInstance()` anymore, use globally-available `browser` object:

```
this.title = browser.getTitle();
```

And, yes, this was a breaking change in `1.5.0`, see:

- [Breaking Changes](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes)

Comment: Wow, very embarrassed that I missed that in the notes. Everything is running 100% again. Will mark as correct when I can. Cheers!